# XSLT 1.0 to detect docx extension

Tags: xml, xslt

I want a way in XSLT to detect docx extension when the file name contain not only one dot
for example:

> Filename...docx

or

> Filename.(2).docx

so in this case, if we use the following code not work :

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-after(@sourcefilename,'.')"/>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!, Please add what you are trying, what is the problem context, what you have tried so far, what is exact problem you are facing and what is not working. Question is bit not clear because of statement 'if we use the following code not work :' check once: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Do you only ever want to check for `.docx` at the end of a filename? Or do you actually need some code that will get the file extension of any file you give it?

Comment: If it is possible to get only .docx at the end of filename that's will resolve the issue can you help me for that many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really only want to check if the filename ends with ".docx" and don't want it more generic, you can just do this...

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring(@sourcefilename, string-length(@sourcefilename) - 4)"/>
```

Or, if you like, in an `xsl:choose`

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="substring(@sourcefilename, string-length(@sourcefilename) - 4) = '.docx'">Is DocX</xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>Is Not DocX</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Although bear in mind, this is case-sensitive, so in XSLT 1.0, you have to do a bit more work if you want to check for ".DOCX" too, for example

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="translate(
                    substring(@sourcefilename, string-length(@sourcefilename) - 4),
                    'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
                    'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') = '.docx'">Is DocX</xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>Is Not DocX</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

If you could upgrade to XSLT 2.0 (or 3.0) you could simplify it to this

```
<xsl:when test="ends-with(lower-case(@sourcefilename), '.docx')">Is DocX</xsl:when>
```